# Tying tether on old luggage rack

Tags: road-bike, vintage, rack, touring-bikes

I've got a bike with an ultra-old luggage rack which isn't of the kind which has a cheap spring-loaded "clasp" but rather an elastic tether which is permanently attached to the frame at the front and is held in place by its own tension on a metal hook at the back:

[image: Bike rack with loose tether]

However, while working on the bike, I removed the rack and now don't know how to properly wrap the tether so that it stays tight: It used to have some sort of "sailor-esque" smart looping method which kept the hook at the end taut, but my landlubber self undid the knot and now doesn't know how to tie the tether properly, so now there's a huge amount of extra slack and the whole bit is loose. **What sort of knot-fu do I need to make the tether taut on the rack?**

[image: Closeup]

Comment: Are you positive the length is right ?      If its right while empty, then it would be too short to hold parcels at full stretch.  Can you take up the slack at the forward-end of the bungee or are both ends fastened permanently ?

Comment: Yes, the length is right. Like I stated, there was some strange knot at the end which took up the remaining slack: The bungee tether can be pulled through the hooks at the end but it was somehow tied around the hooks to make it shorter.

Comment: If you just want to take up slack put a *figure 8* or *figure 9* knot in it. A Google search will yield pics and instructions.

Comment: @Criggie I added a closeup of the hook in the hopes of making it more obvious what I mean exactly...

Comment: Are the ends of the bungee securely fastened or removable? (Near the seatstays).  Because if you can undo one end, you might be able to use something like a [midshipman's hitch](https://www.netknots.com/rope_knots/midshipmans-hitch)

Comment: Note that elastic stretches and becomes unstretchy over time. You might just want to replace it with a new length of bungie cord. Otherwise, it might snap at anytime without notice.

Comment: @errantlinguist didja find an answer?

Comment: @Pete unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

No knot is required - you just need to take up the slack in the bungee / elastic.  Something like this:

[image]

That way you can unhook the bungee for strapping over a large thing but its still tense enough to hold itself down when empty.

Comment: This looks nice, but the bungee is not nearly long enough to do that. It definitely did not look like that before.

Comment: @errantlinguist Its elastic - there will be stretch.  Then reposition the hooks at the 2/3 crossbar.

Comment: The bungee may have aged and lost the ability to stretch. You may need to replace with a new bungee

Comment: Looking back on this answer, I've made an assumption that the hook part on the right (rear) is separate to the main carrier's rack part.  So it could be re-positioned at 2 or 3 other places on the rack, where the transverse rails are.